# Preventing NServiceBus from logging my Azure storage connection string

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, nservicebus

How to prevent NServiceBus from logging my Azure storage connection string?

> 24/05/2014
>   10:55:21  NServiceBus.Unicast.Subscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptions.MessageDrivenSubscriptionManager:
>   Subscribing to Test.Service.Messages.Events.BalanceUpdatedEvent,
>   Test.Service.Messages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null at publisher queue
>   Test@DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=XXX;AccountKey=YYY

Comment: Does this happen at every logging level?

Comment: Which logging framework are you using? Depending on that you could configure it to leave these out

Comment: PS: the long term solution for is to decouple the logical endpoint address from the physical endpoint address and only log the logical information, but this can't be done easily

Comment: @YvesGoeleven, I am using log4net. Separating physical and logical endpoint addresses would do the trick, but I also think that it would be a lot of work. My idea (still not implemented) is to intercept all log messages and just remove AccountKey=YYY part.

Answer (score 0):

Log4net has a filter mechanism that allows you to use StringMatchFilter to specify which content should not be logged. Maybe this can help?

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.StringMatchFilter">
   <stringToMatch value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=" />
   <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
</filter>
```